# Adding native bottom menu to phonegap app for android

Tags: android, cordova

I know there are a few workarounds to create an always visible bottom menu and still be able to scroll the content. (iscroll, jquery)

But isn't it possible to add this in the java file itself and then "communicate" with it. (highlight when selected and such) and the webview only extends to the bottom menu?

Or does anybody knows if there is an easy way with the new update 1.9 where their own webview is included? They haven't included many examples yet.

I know most people swear by jquery/prototype and all these frameworks, but i have heard that the speed of phonegap apps can be very slow, so i want to try making the app without an extra JS framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for some reason, position:fixed worked all of the sudden. I have no idea why??

This basically does what I want it to do with a menu in the bottom.. If I only could figure out what made the difference..

Answer (score 3):

Dan you'd be better off sticking with the Android way of providing this functionality which is providing an options menu that appears when you click the menu button.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

From there in your onOptionsItemSelected method you can call a Javascript function using this.sendJavascript().

Comment: I'm writing up a tutorial on how to do this with PG 2.2.0 right now. Should be out early this week on my blog.

Comment: I read your tutorial, and it worked great for me. Thanks! Here it is: [Building a Native Menu with PhoneGap Android](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2012/11/building-native-menu-with-phonegap.html)